# Safari's "Float:right" causing inline div elements to act as block elements

Tags: html, css

My problem is particular to Safari. Namely, inside of my header is a div consisting of two buttons. The div is floated to the right. But, this 'float:right' makes the two button elements behave like block elements - with each on a different line. I've tried applying the "clear" property to the div, to no avail. I've also tried applying "display: table" to parent div and changing child elements accordingly. All to no avail. The problem is not present in Firefox or Chrome. I have not been able to test it in IE yet - nothing but macs in the house.

I tried to upload two pictures showing the site in Firefox and Safari, but I was denied since I don't have the 10 reputation points necessary to post pictures.

Here's the HTML:

```
        <header role="banner">
        <!--Start Navigation-->
            <nav role="navigation" id="global-navigation">
                    <ul><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>
                    <a href="----">Link 1</a></li><li>
                    <a href="----">Link 2</a></li><li>
                    <a href="----">Link 3</a></li><li>
                    <a href="----">Link 4</a></li><li>
                    <a href="----">Link 5</a></li>
                    <!--Start Signup/LogIn Div-->
                        <div id="signup-login">
                            <button type="button" onclick="----">sign-up</button>
                            <button type="button" onclick="----">log-in</button>
                        </div>
                    <!--End Signup/LogIn Div-->
                    </ul>
            </nav>
        <!--End Navigation-->
        </header>`
```

Here's the CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#global-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    margin: auto;
}

#global-navigation ul {
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    }

#global-navigation ul li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2%;
    padding: 0 3em;
    }



#global-navigation ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 4em; /***Vertically centers global-nav text ***/
    vertical-align: center;
    }

#global-navigation ul li:hover {
    background: #e74c3c;
    transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
    } 

#signup-login {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; 
    line-height: 4em;
    } 

#signup-login button {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    height: 3em;
    width: 4vw;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 7%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .7em;
}

#signup-login button:hover {
    background: #e74c3c;
    transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: background-color .30s ease-in-out;
   border-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
   border-radius: 7%;
   }
```

Comment: These two statements seem to conflict: "My problem is particular to Safari." "The problem is not present in Firefox or Safari." Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Please forgive my mistake. I meant: the problem is not present in Firefox or Chrome**. The mistake has been corrected via edit.

Comment: if you remove `width: 4vw;` or change it to (for example!!) `width: 70px` or `padding: 5px 10px;` on `#signup-login button`... that should work on most modern browser: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/duqudodetaze/1/edit) - Info for support [vw unit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Thank you @aldanux. Setting width to a pixel-based value did the trick. And thank you for the the link you've shared. I have a feeling I will be referencing it often.